# Variable not changing outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have created a function where I am checking the value of an input field and using the number entered as a variable. How do I write my code so the variable can be used outside of this function? For example, change the rays to equal val?

```
var val = $('input').val();
$('input').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    init(val);
});

var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),

    opts = {
        rays: val,
```

Comment: What do you mean, usable outside the method?  First off, you have two `val` variables, as you scoped them both with var, so changes to the inner one do not change the outer one.  You can "fix" that by removing the var from the one in the event handler.

Comment: I have changed the question slightly as this did not work, can you please help? @Taplar

Comment: Presumably this is scope related: https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/

Comment: If you want the new `val` to be used some where, you have to pass it to a method, or have the logic that will use it after it is available.  The logic as you have it, after the click handler, is not going to automatially re-run.  That that logic, put it in a function, and call that function from the click handler, passing in the value

Comment: @Taplar do you have an example, please? post it as an answer if possible?

Comment: I would need a more complete example of what you are trying to do with the val, before I felt comfortable making an answer.

Comment: if you are expecting to change something else that is using it, than you are going to have to rethink your code. It is not going to adjust everything that references it.

Comment: If this helps I have added full js to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhorsy6j/

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  var val = $(this).val();
```

by

```
  val = $(this).val();
```

else you are redefining the variable.

Comment: It helps the asker much more if you actually explain why they are to make such a change.

Comment: thanks for the help, it does not work for what i need, I have changed the question slightly could you please readress?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are struggling here with variable scope. When you use the keyword `var` inside of your change function you are locally scoping a variable of the same name as your globally scoped variable. This overrides the global variable, but only in the scope of the local function.

```js
var val = '';

var init = function(value) {
  var $test = $('.test');
  $test.html(value);
}

$('input').change(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    init(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<br />
<div class="test"></div>
```

Here is another example without the added complexity of jQuery. The console logs before and after the function call rely on the variable in the global scope, the function relies on its local scope.

```
var test = 'test';

function doStuff() {
  var test = 'different test';
  console.log(test);
}
console.log(test);
doStuff();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the vanilla version is looking nice. I am struggling to translate the new names with the code I have already. Please could you write this using the code I have supplied?

Comment: I included a minimal working example of your question at the top (your code snippet didn't do anything on its own). The vanilla js was just a clearer way to explain where things were going wrong :).

Comment: Adding the JS without the HTML in a fiddle doesn't help reproduce the issue :). I would recommend reading up on [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) examples, and since it looks like you may be newer here [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) could be helpful as well.  Additionally if you look at the top example in my answer you will see that it is executable right here in SO no fiddle necessary. To do that you can use the editor, it is a button up near where the code block button is. Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) which binds a function to an Object property and uses the return value of that function each time the property is looked up.

You also need to change

```
var val = $(this).val();//inside the change event handler
```

To

```
val = $(this).val();
```

This way, you are not redeclaring a local-scoped val variable and are instead reassigning a value to the global val variable.

```
var opts = {
    get rays(){
       return val;
    }
}
```

```js
var val = $('input').val();
$('input').change(function(){
    val = $(this).val();
    console.log('val:',val);
    console.log('opts.rays:', opts.rays);
});
var opts = {
    get rays(){
       return val;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```